# Does a Rails console get it's own hardware thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby/Rails app (using the default interpreter), I don't believe I've configured anything to make it use multiple threads. But I'm wondering how does this impact opening up a rails console to a production server that's handling regular traffic? Is rails giving my console its own hardware thread that's being used to execute my commands? Does this mean I have to worry about thread safety when modifying mutable storage via the console, say for example a file on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the rails console it loads a completely separate copy of your application from the server. The only thing they share is the database. So, thread safety isn't an issue, but you might still need to be mindful of accessing/mutating shared resources like database records or files.